How can I have multiple firebase database realtime listeners active in my ESP32?
I am trying to create a plant watering device controlled by an ESP32 which is configured online through firebase database. There are a bunch of variables such as the command to water some plant, adjusting the duration of watering, or the moisture threshold at which watering is automatically activated.
On the following code I have a short version of the structure I am using, which consists of creating one streaming channel for each variable I need to  update in the ESP32 so it works as desired. The problem is that considering all the different watered plants it controls, there should be 20 different streaming channels, which causes instability in ESP32, failing all updates. What would be an advisable solution? I heard there would be a way to use only one streaming channel for all these 20 variables I would like to control from firebase.
I'm currently using Firebase_ESP_Client.h (By Mobitz) as library. There is an older version of the same library that could do the job by accessing multiple paths with only one stream listener, but it was deprecated because of its "unsolvable problems".

FirebaseData fbdo, fbdo_s1, fbdo_s2; 

  
  if (!Firebase.RTDB.beginStream(&fbdo_s1, ReadingPeriodPath))
    Serial.printf("erro ao estabelecer a stream1:", fbdo_s1.errorReason().c_str());

  if (!Firebase.RTDB.beginStream(&fbdo_s2, ReadEverythingNowPath))
    Serial.printf("erro ao estabelecer a stream2:", fbdo_s2.errorReason().c_str()); 

void loop() {
// get from firebase the Period (in seconds) required for each cycle of automatic readings to be activated
  if (Firebase.ready() && signupOK) {
    if (!Firebase.RTDB.readStream(&fbdo_s1))
      Serial.printf("stream1 não pôde ser processada corretamente", fbdo_s1.errorReason().c_str());
    if (fbdo_s1.streamAvailable()) {
      if (fbdo_s1.dataType() == "int") {
        ReadingPeriod = fbdo_s1.intData();
        ReadingPeriod_in_msec = ReadingPeriod * 1000;
        Serial.println("RECEBIDO de Firebase " + fbdo_s1.dataPath() + " : " + ReadingPeriod + " (" + fbdo_s1.dataType() + ")");
      }
    }
  }
}

